# Downloading a project from github

Tags: github, download

The [link](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/lollipop-mr1-fi-release/samples/SearchableDictionary) to the project I would like to download.
I can't see any clone or download button at the right. How can I download the whole project in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the download link:
[Android-PlatformDevelopment-Lollipop-MR1-Fi-Release](https://github.com/android/platform_development/archive/lollipop-mr1-fi-release.zip)

You should click in platform-development so you can get to the main project page, then you will see the Clone Project Button.

Answer (score 0):

You could download part of the project using [**sparse checkout**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951). So what you need is just:

> git clone https://github.com/android/platform_development.git

or

> git clone git@github.com:android/platform_development.git